# Typescript String Literal Types not working in function overloading

Tags: typescript, overloading

According to TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (look for the **String Literal Types** section), the following code should work on TypeScript:

```
function createElement(tagName: "img"): HTMLImageElement;
function createElement(tagName: "input"): HTMLInputElement;
// ... more overloads ...

function createElement(tagName: string): Element {
    // ... code goes here ...
}
```

When I run the code, or some more meaningful variation, on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), or on Visual Studio, I get the following error:

```
Specialized overload signature is not assignable to any non-specialized signature.
```

Any suggestion? I came to this error after trying to implement something very similar on my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to start with a non specialized signature?

```
function createElement(tagName: string): Element;
function createElement(tagName: "img"): HTMLImageElement;
function createElement(tagName: "input"): HTMLInputElement;
// ... more overloads ...

function createElement(tagName: string): Element { /* ... */ }
```

```

Comment: It works, thanks! Great!
Do you have any explanation why does it work? I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Not sure, maybe because specialized signatures can't see the implementation that comes after them? More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32212966/3478605).

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question:
IMHO, the use of Generics can solve this kind of problems in a better way.

**String Literals + Function Overloading approach**

```
function createElement(tagName: string): Element;
function createElement(tagName: "img"): HTMLImageElement;
function createElement(tagName: "input"): HTMLInputElement;
// ... more overloads ...

function createElement(tagName: string): Element { /* ... */ }

var inputElement = createElement("input");
```

**Generics approach**

```
function createElement<elementType>(): elementType { /* ... */ }

var inputElement = createElement<HTMLInputElement>();
```

**Generics approach with stronger type constraints**

```
function createElement<elementType extends HTMLElement>(): elementType { /* ... */ }

var inputElement = createElement<HTMLInputElement>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict to **only** the specified strings (e.g. when other cases are an error) you apparently have to alias the type first.

```
type ValidTagOptions = "img" | "input";
function createElement(tagName: ValidTagOptions): HTMLImageElement;
function createElement(tagName: ValidTagOptions): HTMLInputElement;
```

This is trigger a compiler error when calling:

```
createElement("a"); // Error!
```

You can't just start doing it with the literals in the function signature, as you found. Annoying, IMO. I hope they clean this up in future TS versions!